# Semantic UI Multiple Search Dropdown - onRemove not removing label

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

I'm using semantic UI for a project and I just got into a little issue.

On my multiple search dropdown I want to be able to remove labels and do a callback function when doing so.

The callback function works fine but, the label is not being removed when clicked on the cross. It just stays there as if I selected it.

I'm also using Angular JS for this project, so here's the directive for the dropdown:

```
app.directive('dropdownSearchPersonalities', function () {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var personalitiesLength = scope.student.personalities.length;
            var studentPersonalities = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < personalitiesLength; i++) {
                studentPersonalities[i] = scope.student.personalities[i].name;
            }

            $(elem).dropdown({
                allowAdditions : true,
                onAdd: function (value) {
                    if(personalitiesLength) {
                        if($.inArray(value, studentPersonalities) != -1)
                            return;
                        else
                            scope.addPersonality(value, scope.studentId);
                    } else {
                        scope.addPersonality(value, scope.studentId);
                    }
                },
                onRemove: function (value, text, choice) {
                    scope.removePersonality(value, scope.studentId);
                }
            });

            $(elem).dropdown('set selected', studentPersonalities);
        }
    }
});
```

I repeat, the only thing that doesn't work is that the label is not removed, if I refresh the page the label that was meant to be removed is gone.

Here's an image of how it looks when trying to remove:

[image]

The cursor doesn't show up, but its actually over the cross icon.

Anyone has encountered this issue? How can I solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't see anything in the documentation but can you try returning 'true' from the onRemove method after you call removePersonality?

Comment: @FerVargas did you find a solution? I am having a similar issue - the selected items remain in the UI but are actually removed when I get the values from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onChange`, then in your inputs (event, data), the 'data' part will detect if you click on the 'x' or if you add a label. For example:

```
onChange (event, data) {
  this.setState({
    data: { ...this.state.data, [data.name]: data.value}
  });
}
```

The value automatically updates your array with all the options selected.